# Save datapicker date into wordpress admin

Tags: metabox, datepicker

i have question: http://prntscr.com/frxplp i need when user pick to date in datapicker and press button and filled all field in form http://prntscr.com/frxr7g, need to save this data with selected date in wp-admin metabox in admin page, if possible tell how i can do this better

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to insert images into your post - see the bottom of formatting page:[Formatting Images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Can you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/272373/edit) and add in the code you're currently using to save your data?

Comment: I can add only via database: $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_dates ". "(checkin, checkout) ". "VALUES('$checkin','$checkout',)"; but maybe via wordpress possible add?